# conditional probability distribution function - other way round

Tags: probability

I apologize, that I could not find a better wording for the title, but this is my question:

I know that the conditional probability distribution function of two continuous variables $X$ and $Y$, given by $f(x \mid y)$ can be interpreted as $P(X \leq x \mid Y=y)$, that is probability of $X \leq x$ given $Y$ is definitely $y$.

I wonder, if a function of the shape $g(x \mid y)$ exists,which is interpreted as $P(X \leq x \mid Y \in (y -\epsilon , y + \epsilon )$. What is such a function called? Is such a function a topic of study in any field related to mathematics?

I apologize for the relative less eloquence of the question, but I would really like to know.

Comment: Assuming that the second $\mid$ in your last formula is a _comma_, yes the function is just the conditional CDF of $X$ conditioned on the event $\{Y \in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\}$.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As  Dilip Sarwate wrote, it does exist (unless $P(Y\in(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon) = 0$). Also under reasonable assumptions, 
$$
P(X \leq x \mid Y =y ) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+} P\big(X \leq x \mid Y \in (y -\epsilon , y + \epsilon )\big),
$$
so it does have some useful properties.

Comment: and what happens if $\epsilon \not \rightarrow 0 $ ? Can I also expect a general form as $Y \in (y-a, y+a)$?

Comment: @Sean, what do you mean by "general form"?

Comment: By that i mean a case, where $\epsilon$ does not tend to zero